# Trying to get property on non-object with Laravel 5.1 and Vue 2

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I have a url loading with data passed on from Laravel.  I place the data in the vue data using blade syntax like this:

```
data: {
    id: "{!! ($header->id) !!}",
    vendor: '{!! $header->vendor_name !!}',
    orderDate: '{!! $header->orderDate !!}',
    list: [],
}
```

So far so good. The data is set properly.

Then there is a method that triggers when a row in the table is clicked:

```
methods: {
   findInventoryItem: function(rowId) {
       var header = this.id;
       url = '{!! url('part-order/find-inventory') !!}' + '?headerId=' + header + '&rowId=' + rowId;
       window.location.href = url;
   }
```

The url is setup properly.

The error happens when I click the table row.  This error pops up.

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /code/zone/resources/views/parts/part-order.blade.php)
```

Notice that the error is not with the requested url but with the existing url.

The error is triggered by this line:

```
id: "{!! ($header->id) !!}",
```

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Comment: Note that you should almost always use `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}` unless you explicitly want to allow HTML to be outputted. Otherwise you're opening yourself up to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Please, write `{{ dd($header) }}` and post the result here.

Comment: @Laerte The result is a collection object.  Quite big to be posted here.  What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why $header is not considered an object in this case. This errors usually occurs when you send an array or a string instead of an object and try to get an attribute from it.

Comment: The problem here is that my method requests /part-order/find-inventory?.... and this is what shows up on the url identifier in the browser when the error occurs.  But the error shows up as it is leaving the url /parts/part-order.  It's as if it was trying to reload the current url before continuing on to the requested url.  If it is trying to reload the current url; then it makes sense that it would throw the error because the data.id value is passed on from the server by laravel.

Comment: Why is it checking the value of data.id of the current url if it is supposed to be going to the requested url?

Comment: It is probably not checking again. What it is probably doing is calling that url,  trying to find the new hear based on the parameter headerId and then a problem is happening, for example, it is not finding anything and trying to get and id, or sending a bad formatted result or something like that. I would look into something like this...

Comment: I modified the data to be actual strings instead of populating from blade.  The error does not show up anymore.  Strange enough the url changes but the view page stays the same.  Hmmm. Something strange going on because my routes are setup correctly.  I need to investigate a little further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a rookie mistake but I found the issue.  The worst part is that I have made this mistake before.  It had nothing to do with Laravel or Vue.  Sometimes explaining your problem and discussing it with someone helps to identify and figure out what you did wrong.  Thanks @Laerte for discussing with me.  It helped me find the solution.

The problem was in the routes.  The following route was interfering.

```
Route::get('part-order/{id}', 'PartOrderController@showOrder');
```

and my requested route was

```
Route::get('part-order/find-inventory', 'PartOrderController@findInventoryNumber');
```

Since my first route had a variable in the second segment, I couldn't use the other route without adding a third segment.  Because the second segment was interpreted as a variable and so never reached it in my request.

I fixed the route like this:

```
Route::get('part-order/find-inventory/inv', 'PartOrderController@findInventoryNumber');
```

Comment: Nice to know that I helped you to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This error says that `$header` is `null`. You need to check it for `null`. Something like:

```
{!! is_null($header) ? 0 : $header->id !!}
```

Or:

```
@if (!is_null($header))
    {!! $header->id !!}
@endif
```

Comment: It's not null to begin with so how does it become null?

Comment: @Robbie I can't answer that since I don't see the code.